# ADF checkboxes in table, selected row missing timing

Tags: java, oracle-adf

I have a table where the first column is supposed to be a checkbox so that you can select a bunch of rows and for now, just add it to a list stored in the pageflowscope. The problem is that clicking on the checkboxes sometimes has the selected row lagging behind and adds the wrong row. Ex. I click the checkbox in the first row, then while it processes, I uncheck it then click another checkbox, it'll add the first row still because it thinks the selected row is still the first row.

Table:

```
 <af:table value="#{bindings.documents.collectionModel}" var="row" rows="#{bindings.documents.rangeSize}"
                  emptyText="#{bindings.documents.viewable ? 'No data to display.' : 'Access Denied.'}"
                  rowBandingInterval="0" selectedRowKeys="#{bindings.documents.collectionModel.selectedRow}"
                  selectionListener="#{bindings.documents.collectionModel.makeCurrent}" rowSelection="single"
                  fetchSize="#{bindings.documents.rangeSize}" filterModel="#{bindings.documentsQuery.queryDescriptor}"
                  filterVisible="true" queryListener="#{bindings.documentsQuery.processQuery}" varStatus="vs" id="t1"
                  autoHeightRows="0" styleClass="AFStretchWidth" scrollPolicy="page">
            <af:column id="c41" align="center" width="50">
                <?audit suppress oracle.adf.faces.tablecolneedsheaders?>
                <af:selectBooleanCheckbox id="sbc1" valueChangeListener="#{CopyQueueBean.toggleCheckbox}"
                                          autoSubmit="true">
                    <?audit suppress oracle.adf.faces.compnotlabelled?>
                </af:selectBooleanCheckbox>
            </af:column>

            <af:column sortProperty="#{bindings.documents.hints.id.name}" filterable="true" sortable="true"
                       headerText="#{labels.ID}" id="c1" align="center">
                <af:outputText value="#{row.id}" shortDesc="#{bindings.documents.hints.id.tooltip}" id="ot1"/>
            </af:column>
            <af:column sortProperty="#{bindings.documents.hints.fileName.name}" filterable="true" sortable="true"
                       headerText="#{labels.TITLE}" id="c4" align="center" width="400">
                <af:panelGroupLayout id="pgl2" styleClass="AFStretchWidth" inlineStyle="float:left; text-align:left;">
                        <af:spacer width="20px" id="leftIconSpacer" />
                        <af:image source="#{row.icon}" id="i6"
                                  inlineStyle="width:40.0px;"/>
                        <af:spacer width="40px" id="iconSpacer" />
                        <af:outputText value="#{row.fileName}" id="fot2"/>
                    </af:panelGroupLayout>
            </af:column>
```

My Bean method:

```
public void toggleCheckbox(ValueChangeEvent valueChangeEvent) {
    // Add event code here...
    Boolean checked = (Boolean) valueChangeEvent.getNewValue();
    //get list
    ADFContext adfCtx = ADFContext.getCurrent();
    Map params = adfCtx.getPageFlowScope();
    List<Row> list = (List<Row>) params.get("docQueue");
    if (list == null) {
        list = new ArrayList<CopyQueuePojo>();
    }

    DCBindingContainer bindings = (DCBindingContainer) BindingContext.getCurrent().getCurrentBindingsEntry();
    DCIteratorBinding documents = bindings.findIteratorBinding("documentsIterator");
    int index = documents.getCurrentRowIndexInRange();

    Row[] rows = documents.getAllRowsInRange();
    Row line = rows[index];

    if (checked) {
        //add to queue
        if (index >=  0) {                
            //check to make sure there are no duplicates
            boolean exists = false;
            for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
                if(list.get(i).getId() == ((String) line.getAttribute("id"))) {
                    exists = true; 
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!exists) {                    
                list.add(line);
            }
        }
    } else {
        //remove from queue
        for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
            if(list.get(i).getId() == ((String) line.getAttribute("id"))) {
                list.remove(i);
            }
        }
    }
    params.put("docQueue", list);
}
```

JDEVELOPER: 12.2.1.2.0

Should I be using a different way to set the selected row? or should I not be using valuechangelistener? or is it something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to add a selectBooleanCheckbox to a table based on a ViewObject is to add a boolean transient value to your viewObject. Doing so will allow you to have a different boolean value saved for each row and to easily access it in the same ways as the other column values.

To do so :

1) Add a isSelected Boolean transient attribute to your ViewObject:

```
<ViewAttribute
Name="isSelected"
IsSelected="false"
IsPersistent="false"
PrecisionRule="true"
Type="java.lang.Boolean"
ColumnType="NUMBER"
AliasName="VIEW_ATTR"
SQLType="BIT"
Passivate="true">
<DesignTime>
  <Attr Name="_diagramName" Value=" "/>
</DesignTime>
<Properties>
  <SchemaBasedProperties>
    <CONTROLTYPE
      Value="check_box"/>
    <DISPLAYWIDTH
      Value="10"/>
    <DISPLAYHEIGHT
      Value="10"/>
  </SchemaBasedProperties>
</Properties>
```

2) Drag and drop your ViewObject as a table to your view, you should have the following column added :

```
<af:column sortable="false" id="c1" width="20">
    <af:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{row.bindings.isSelected.inputValue}" label="#{row.bindings.isSelected.label}" id="sbc1"/>
</af:column>
```

3) In your Bean actions, easily get your boolean value :

```
    Boolean val = (Boolean )JSFUtils.resolveExpression("#{row.bindings.isSelected.inputValue}");
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm still working on it, I'll come back when I'm done, doing it this way changes a lot of things for me.

Comment: Finally managed to get it working, I added a boolean for the checkbox in the viewobject, then modified my bean method to loop through all rows in the iterator to find all rows that had been checked and changed it to run on form submit rather than on checkbox click